# How to make invisible a TextBlock after a few seconds?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Can you tell me please if there is a way to make invisible a TextBlock after a few seconds, or when you see a different HubSection even if the TextBlock is not declared within the control HUB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer tmr;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tmr = new Timer();
            tmr.Interval = 3 * 1000; // 3 seconds
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
            tmr.Start();
        }

        void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            tmr.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

In WPF, you can use a DispatcherTimer to do the same thing:

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
myDispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100); // 100 Milliseconds 
myDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
myDispatcherTimer.Start();


public void tmr_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender)
{
    myTextBlock.Text = "test";
}
```

Comment: As I wrote in the tags, I'm not doing a WPF, but a Windows-phone app